# Imacros (javascript) getting variable value from custom input dialog

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to find a way to create custom user input dialog with imacros (javascript).

However while the dialog itself could be done, say,

[with javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGb8g.jpg)

[or jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBNLZ.png)

No luck in getting the variable to be used "outside". It keeps saying variable is not defined, or illegal syntax (see i am trying to alert "a" variable outside)

Is there any way to get around this issue, attaining the goal? Or i am doing it wrong?

**P.S:** I am using imacros 8.9.7 run in Firefox 56, Windows 7 (classic mode)

Comment: Purpose of the 'PROMPT' Command...

Comment: PROMPT command only show basic-styled single line input, not something i would like to achieve. So its not possible?

Comment: @chivracq The goal is to create custom modal popup (multi line input) that is heavily styled, then use that input for the rest. I am sure it could be done somehow

Comment: "single line", => Not True, you can use '<BR>' for Multi-Lines... (and '<SP>' for Spaces). (But no Bold/Italic/etc, and you can't change the Lettertype...) And you can only use 1 Input Field per 'PROMPT'. But if ask the Users to input the Data like "Input 1 # Input 2 # Input 3", you can re-separate the 3 Fields using 'EVAL()', ... or you use 3x 'PROMPT'...

Comment: "1 input field per PROMPT" - exactly my point. Mine have always like 8 variable or so. Some optional, some requires specific format (not just <input> but also <textarea>, etc). Since you're one of the most experienced imacros on earth, from above comment, simply said, are you suggesting that its not possible achieving such goal?

Comment: Yeah don't worry, "just" behave a little bit, ah-ah...! - About "sorry its impossible to do so in imacros", beh..., nope, it's possible in iMacros, (correct Spelling btw!!), I already told you so "earlier" but you seem to have your Mind set to "It's not possible"... Then OK, fair enough, ah-ah...!

Comment: Yep saw that,... and I approved it, still not complying with all iMacros Forum Rules, like I had announced here already... - I would suggest: "Radio Silence" on this Forum, and "we" will post some Update/Solution if any... - In the meantime, Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=31371&p=86755#p86755 for any Interested User(s)...

Comment: @chivracq If you could point out what's missing that would be helpful - I already posted in "iMacros for FF", working code, attach screenshot as well. I believe have also mostly cover what specified in this sticky thread https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3331 , not sure what's left

Comment: Yep parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=31371&p=86757#p86754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still posting as an/"the" Answer a Link to one Post of mine that you "accepted" at "the" Answer/Solution to your Qt @OP in the parallel Thread you opened on the 'iMacros' Forum...:

- [Re: Imacros (javascript) getting variable value from custom input dialog](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=31371&p=86757#p86770)

I won't quote its/(my) Content as it's pretty Verbose with several Links to other Threads on the iMacros Forum and its Content doesn't really fit for the "simplistic" Q/A Principle from SOF which doesn't/never works for [imacros](/questions/tagged/imacros) Qt's, or only for ueber-simplistic Qt's from Users too lazy to read 2 Pages from the Wiki/Documentation...

=> For Users interested, this is a very clever/interesting Qt/Scenario, check the parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum for "more Info"...

---

(@ SOF Mods, I post my Answers/Solutions on the iMacros Forum, (has been around before SOF), as (I make sure) no Content gets deleted there (Mod there sinds 2015, with 9000+ Posts / 1500+ Solutions), while all new Threads/Qt's about [imacros](/questions/tagged/imacros) all get deleted "here" every Friday with just one '-1' from anybody...) (Counter has been at ~1450 for at least 3 years... (for 'iMacros' Qt's...))

- @OP, if you can accept my Answer, to prevent Deletion of the whole Thread...